# Find $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$ of the following linear transformation with bases

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

**Question**: Let T: $\mathbb R^{3} → M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$ be the linear transformation defined by $$T((a,b,c)) = \begin{bmatrix}
         a & 5a\\
         c & 3c\\
        \end{bmatrix} $$

Consider the bases $\alpha = \{(0, 1, 0),(0, 1, 1),(1, 1, 0)\}$ of $\mathbb R^{3}$ and
, 
$\beta = \{{\begin{bmatrix}\
         1 &−1\\
         0 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}} ,{\begin{bmatrix}
         0 & 1\\
         -1 & 0\\
        \end{bmatrix}} ,{\begin{bmatrix}
         0 & 0\\
         1 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix}}, {\begin{bmatrix}
         0 &1\\
         0 & -1\\
        \end{bmatrix}}\}$ of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb R)$. Find $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$ and $\mathrm{Im}(T)$.

**Context**: This question is a practice problem given to us by our introductory linear algebra professor for solving and understanding concepts (Note: this is not an assignment or graded homework question)

**Attempt**:

*Finding $\mathrm{Ker}(T)$*: Row reducing the transformation matrix to RREF would give the matrix \begin{bmatrix}
         1 &0\\
         0 & 1\\
        \end{bmatrix} leaving no free variables thus $\mathrm{Ker}(T)=\mathrm{span}\{0\} $

*Finding $\mathrm{Im}(T)$*: Since there are no free variables, we use the original columns from $T((a,b,c))$ to get our Image i.e.

$\mathrm{Col}(A) =\mathrm{span}\{\begin{bmatrix}
         a \\
         c \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
         5a \\
         3c \\
        \end{bmatrix}\}$. I know we use this with the basis $\beta$ to obtain our image. How do we proceed from here?

Do we perform $a\begin{bmatrix}
         1&-1 \\
         0&0 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + c\begin{bmatrix}
         0&0 \\
         1&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ and $5a\begin{bmatrix}
         1&-1 \\
         0&0 \\
        \end{bmatrix} + 3c\begin{bmatrix}
         0&0 \\
         1&1 \\
        \end{bmatrix}$?

This gives us $\mathrm{Im}(T) = \mathrm{span} \{\begin{bmatrix}
         a&-a \\
         c&c \\
        \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
         a&-5a \\
         3c&3c \\
        \end{bmatrix}\}$.

**Doubt**: Is this correct or am I going about this the wrong way? I have a feeling I made a mistake because according to the R-N theorem, my rank and nullity must add up to $3$ but at this point, it adds up to $2$.

Comment: You have $T(a,b,c)$ but in the matrix there is no $b$?

Comment: Yes, that is how the question was provided to us. No b in the transformation matrix.

Comment: That given matrix is not the transformation matrix.

Comment: My apologies. I mean the matrix corresponding to T(a,b,c)

Comment: Also, $T$ transforms any $(0, b, 0)$ to a zero matrix, so there is something in the kernal.

Comment: What do the given bases have to do with the question? Are you supposed to express the image and kernel relative to them?

Comment: @amd yes i think so. that's what happened with some similar questions but the answers below seem useful too *shrugs*

Comment: Once you’ve gotten a solution relative to the standard bases, the hard work is done. Converting to other bases is straightforward.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the three standard unit vectors,

$$\begin{align*}
T(1,0,0) &= \pmatrix{1&5\\0&0}\\
T(0,1,0) &= \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}\\
T(0,0,1) &= \pmatrix{0&0\\1&3}\\
T(a,b,c) &= a\pmatrix{1&5\\0&0} + c\pmatrix{0&0\\1&3}
\end{align*}$$

Kernal: Solving the equation $T(a,b,c) = \pmatrix{0&0\\0&0}$ gives $a=c=0$ and $b$ is a free variable, so a basis of the kernal is $\{(0,1,0)\}$.

Image: The two matrices $\pmatrix{1&5\\0&0}$ and $\pmatrix{0&0\\1&3}$ are already linearly independent, so they form the basis of the image of $T$.

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense!

Answer (score 4):

Note that $T$ maps to the space of $2\times 2$ matrices, which, as a vector space is just a $4$ dimensional space: arranging the $4$ coordinates in $2\times 2$ matrix or column or row has no significance in such a context.

The image of $T$ just consists of all matrices of the form $\pmatrix{a&5a\\c&3c}$, so it is spanned by 
$$B_1:=\pmatrix{1&5\\0&0}\quad\quad B_2:=\pmatrix{0&0\\1&3}$$
because $T(a,b,c)=a\cdot B_1+c\cdot B_2$. 
Clearly, they are not scalar multiples of each other, so $\dim{\rm im}T=2$.

By the dimension theorem, then we'll have $\dim\ker T=1$, and as $b$ is not used in the formula for $T$, any $(0,b,0)$ is in the kernel (a basis of it is the one vector $(0,1,0)$).

Answer (score 4):

The "kernel" of a linear transformation is the subspace of the domain space of all vectors that are transformed into the 0 vector.  Here that would give $T(a, b, c)= \begin{bmatrix}a & 5a \\ c & 3c\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so that we must have $ a= 0, 5a= 0, c= 0, 3c= 0$. That is, $a= c= 0.$  Because there is no $'b'$ in that, $b$ can be anything.  So the kernel consists of all vectors of the form $(0, b, 0)$, the one dimensional subspace spanned by $(0, 1, 0).$

The "image" of a linear transformation is the subspace of the range space of all vectors that something in the domain is mapped to.  Here, any $(a, b, c)$ is mapped into $\begin{bmatrix}u & v \\ w & x\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} a & 5a \\ c & 3c\end{bmatrix}$.  That means that $v= 5u$ and $x= 3c$.  So the image consists of matrices $\begin{bmatrix}u & 5u \\ c & 3c\end{bmatrix}= u\begin{bmatrix}1 & 5 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}+ v\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 \\ 1 & 3 \end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: Thank you! This helped :)

Answer (score 3):

You say that the kernel $Ker(T) = \{0\}$

What happends if you calculate $T(0,b,0)$?

Remember that $ImT = \{ M \in M_{2\times 2} : M = T(a,b,c) \ (a,b,c) \in \mathbb{R^3}\}$